# how to match one sheet column data with another sheet?

Tags: vba

i have 2 workbook and i want to match workbook-1 sheet one column with another workbook-2 sheet one column,if 2 cell is same match ID then return header.

For example: 
i want to return the Workbook-2 Header such as like A001 if my "X" marked ID all is match with workbook-1 ID.

The expected outcome like the "Output" Sheet in workbook-2

Workbook-1

[image]

workbook-2

[image]

outcome example

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code started?

Comment: Is that output the final outcome you're expecting? What about all the other rows in Workbook1? Just keep looping through and adding to the same output? So a bunch of A001, A005,A001, yada yada? That doesn't seem like what you'd want as a final output, or based on what?

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code i had no idea with this so i am finding some suggestion.thanks

Comment: @PGCodeRider the output is expecting result,the "datasheet" is the references for giving "match"sheet to match and return the result like "output" sheet.thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took a stab at this even though it doesn't make much sense to me. It requires that the three sheets you're using use the exact sheet names in the screenshot and no other sheets share the name. I didn't test it but

```
Sub WhatTheHeckisThis()
Dim WKBK As Workbook, wsStart As Worksheet, wsLookup As Worksheet, wsOutput As Worksheet
Dim lineLookup As Range, i As Long, yCell As Range, rCell As Range


Dim tWSstart As String: tWSstart = "Datasheet"
Dim tWSLookup As String: tWSLookup = "MATCH"
Dim twsOutput As String: twsOutput = "OUTPUT"

For Each WKBK In Application.Workbooks
    For Each WS In WKBK.Sheets
        If UCase(WS.Name) = UCase(tWSstart) Then
            Set wsStart = WS
        ElseIf UCase(WS.Name) = (tWSLookup) Then
            Set wsLookup = WS

        ElseIf UCase(WS.Name) = UCase(twsOutput) Then
            Set wsOutput = WS
        End If
    Next WS
Next WKBK


For Each rCell In Intersect(wsStart.Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count), wsStart.UsedRange).Cells

    Set lineLookup = Nothing
    Set lineLookup = wsLookup.Cells.Find(rCell.Value, _
        After:=wsLookup.Cells.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not lineLookup Is Nothing Then

        For Each yCell In Intersect(lineLookup.EntireRow, wsLookup.UsedRange).Cells

            If UCase(yCell.Value) = "X" Then
                With wsOutput
                i = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                 .Cells(i, 1).Value = i - 1
                .Cells(i, 2).Value = wsLookup.Cells(1, yCell.Column).Value
                End With

            End If
        Next yCell
    End If

Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Set lineLookup = wsLookup.Cells.Find(rCell.Value) this line ruturn a bug, i had attached a file in this link https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1239056-how-to-match-one-sheet-column-data-with-another-sheet.html#post4942333   thanks.

Comment: sry ,still have bug at the same line,error "91" what is that mean?

Comment: @Steph You've Got a SPACE in your worksheet name "MATCH ". Please fix and accept answer. Thanks.